# É possivel determinar o caminho de acesso para o arquivo na Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, java

Tenho uma aplicação ´Java WEB´ onde estou utilizando uma *function* que abre o arquivo **.pdf** que determino, porém ela só abre os arquivos **.pdf** que estão na mesma pasta onde esta salvo meu projeto, já tentei alterar a minha variável `String` que chama o arquivo **.pdf** e colocar o caminho de Acesso, por exemplo, **"C:\teste.pdf"** porém ela nunca acha o arquivo se coloco o caminho junto, é possível alterar o caminho de acesso dos arquivos?

```
<%
        String arquivo = "";
        String i = "";

        try {
            if (request.getParameter("nomeArq").contains("null")){
                arquivo = request.getAttribute("nomeArquivo").toString();
            }else{
                arquivo = request.getParameter("nomeArq");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            arquivo = request.getAttribute("nomeArquivo").toString();
        }
        try {
            i = request.getParameter("numeroPag").toString();
        } catch (Exception a) {
            i = request.getAttribute("pagina").toString();
        }


    %>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            window.onload = function abrirPdf() {
                var iframe = $("#LoteSlips");
                iframe.attr("src", '<%=arquivo%>_ERRO.pdf#zoom=200&page=<%=i%>'); 
            };
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: java? O código mais parece jquery

Comment: Para isso você teria que usar o `file://` no src e executar o Chrome (por exemplo) através do `cmd` passando como parâmetro o `--allow-file-access-from-files`. O browser por questões de segurança não permite acesso aos ficheiros na máquina do cliente.

Comment: A não ser que a aplicação funcione apenas localmente (e mesmo assim faz pouco sentido), não faz sentido o que você quer, caso contrário utilize o caminho absoluto utilizando o protocolo `http` ou o caminho relativo para o arquivo com base no diretório onde o script se encontra.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Tu terias como me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso e onde eu faria essas alterações? Pois o que eu preciso é poder alterar na ´funtion´ o diretório onde os meus arquivos *.pdf estão sem que tenham que ficar salvos junto com o projeto.

Comment: A sua aplicação é só para funcionar localmente? Tem o PHP instalado localmente? Como está o seu ambiente no momento?

Comment: No momento eu tenho uma pagina jsp que cria uma tabela com o nome dos arquivos .pdf que estão no diretório "C:\teste", por exemplo, dai quando clico em abrir mando para essa pagina de visualizar o pdf o nome do arquivo seleciono, só que como não consigo alterar o caminho na function "C:\teste\nome_arq_pdf" preciso salvar os arquivos também junto com meu projeto, vou editar a pergunta pra mostrar como esta minha pagina de visualizar pdf

Comment: Está usando struts? qual versão?

Comment: @DavidSchrammel Struts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você esbarou em um a questão de segurança. Por padrão os navegadores não permitem que as aplicações web acessem arquivos locais sem a permissão do usuário. O que é certo, imagine você acessando um site qualquer, e enquanto você navega o site pega vários arquivos do seu computador. Nada bom não é?

Uma alternativa é você fazer o upload do arquivo, processa-lo no server e devolver o resultado para o *client*. Não sei se isso resolve o seu problema, mas é o que pode ser feito.